# If $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$ and that A is dense in B s odo B is dense in C how do I prove that A is dense in C?

Tags: real-analysis

If $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$ and that $A$ is dense in $B$ s odo $B$ is dense in $C$ how do I prove that $A$ is dense in $C$?

Please provide me with a headstart, greatly appreciated!

Comment: The closure of $A$ is a closed set containing $B$, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $A$ dense in $B$ means that $\mathrm{Cl}(A)\supseteq B$.
- $B$ dense in $C$ means that $\mathrm{Cl}(B)\supseteq C$.
- For every $D$, $\mathrm{Cl}(\mathrm{Cl}(D))=\mathrm{Cl}(D)$.
- Hence....

Answer (score 2):

For the special case where $A \subseteq B \subseteq C \subseteq \Bbb R$, choose any $c_1,c_2 \in C$, where $c_1<c_2$. Then since $B$ is dense in $C$, there exists some $b_1 \in B$ such that $c_1<b_1<c_2$. Now since $B \subseteq C$, we know that $b_1 \in C$, so we may repeat this procedure to the elements $b_1,c_2 \in C$ (since $b_1<c_2$) to obtain some $b_2 \in B$ such that $c_1 < b_1 < b_2 < c_2$. Finally, since $A$ is dense in $B$, $b_1,b_2\in B$, and $b_1 < b_2$, we know that there exists some $a \in A$ such that $c_1 < b_1 < a < b_2 < c_2$. Hence, $A$ is dense in $C$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $X \supset Y \Longrightarrow \overline{X} \supset \overline{Y}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use that $\;D\;$ is dense in $\,X\;$ iff for every non-empty open $\,U\subset X\;,\;\;D\cap U\neq\emptyset\;$ :

Let $\,\emptyset\neq U\subset C\;$, then $\,B\cap U\neq\emptyset\;$ **and also** open in $\,B\,$ , so now with $\,A\cap(B\cap U)\; \ldots$